# Combining rows with nearly same fields

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames and want to combine them into a single data frame. I used a common key to merge two frames. The final result was a data frame that some of rows have nearly identical fields except a few columns have different values. I want to combine these nearly identical rows into a single row considering adding appropriate columns. 
Here are the data frames:

stores:

```
Banner - Region - Store ID 

Walmart - NC - 66999 

TJ - NY - 4698
```

prices:

```
Price - Store ID - UPC 

3.6 - 66999 - 234565 

4.5 - 4698 - 334526
```

I already merged tow frames and played a little bit to converge to the desired frame.

```
store_cross = pd.crosstab(stores['Store ID'],stores['Region'],margins=True)
merged_df2 = pd.merge(store_cross,prices,left_on='Store ID', right_on='Store ID')
merged_df2 = pd.merge(merged_df2,stores,left_on='Store ID', right_on='Store ID')
```

This is the result so far:

```
NY - NC - Price - UPC - Banner 

1 - 0 - 3.6 - 234565 - Walmart 

0 - 1 - 4.5 - 334526 - TJ
```

It is possible to have a UPC at different stores. It means that there are other rows in the frame that have the same UPC and Banner but at different locations.

What I am looking to have is something like this:

```
Banner - UPC - NC - NY 

Walmart - 234565 - 3.9 - 3.6 

TJ - 334526 - 4.5 - 4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need first `merge` and then [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = pd.merge(stores, prices, on='Store ID')
store_cross = df.pivot_table(index=['Banner', 'Store ID','UPC'],
                             columns='Region',
                             values='Price', 
                             aggfunc='sum').reset_index()

print (store_cross)
Region   Banner  Store ID     UPC   NC   NY
0            TJ      4698  334526  NaN  4.5
1       Walmart     66999  234565  3.6  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this would not combine rows that have similar "Banner" and "UPC" but different region. Ideally, all rows that have the same "UPC" and "Banner" should combine in a single row with different region price.